# Creating a child node from a parent node

Tags: c#, devexpress

HII

I am using xtratreelist in this i have a treelist and a button in the form .the button is placed such that when the user clicks  the button a new parent node(root node) is created.

but now i want to create a child node from the parent node while clicking another button ..help me please,,,,

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode("ChildNode");
treeList.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(node);
```